# Which option should I use to avoid error #2006 on MySQL (Docker Compose)

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, errors, docker, my.cnf

I am getting error `#2006 - MySQL server has gone away` while trying to restore a 11.9 mb database using PhpMyAdmin. It worked with a 4.70 mb database, but not with this one

[image]

I thought that if I put `--max-allowed-packet=500M` in command it will work, but still getting the same

```yml
mysql:
    command: --max-allowed-packet=500M
    container_name: db_mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: doadmin
      MYSQL_DATABASE: defaultdb
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysqlpass3434
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysqlrootpass3432523
    image: mysql:8
    networks:
      - internal
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /root/wordpress/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

Note: I am using a $12 USD premium Intel Droplet on Digital Ocean

Comment: The error means that the time needed for the operation is larger than the timeout for a command in the client settings. The client does not receive the signal that the server finished the operation and is ready for the next command and produces this error. Increase this PhpMyAdmin client setting.

Comment: No, it is one of the timeouts, perhaps `SET GLOBAL wait_time = 999999;`

Comment: @RickJames I think that wait_time is not valid in mySQL 8

Comment: Error
SQL query:


SET GLOBAL wait_time = 999999;
MySQL said: 

#1193 - Unknown system variable 'wait_time'

Comment: `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout`.  Note that the setting won't affect any connections that are currently running.

Comment: When I run `docker run -it --rm mysql:8 --verbose --help` I get that those values equal to `interactive-timeout=28800` and `wait-timeout=28800` so I think that those are high enough

Comment: I also used `--max-allowed-packet=500M --log-error-verbosity=3 --connect-timeout=100 --thread-cache-size=100 --innodb-io-capacity=500` and still the same :c